# Get count of files in a folder in an s3 bucket from a python lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-sdk

Is there anyway to get the number of files(objects) in a specific folder in an s3 bucket, from a lambda function using python.

Answer (score 3):

You can the `aws s3 ls` command with the `--summarize -- recursive` flags to get the summary which includes the count of files in the specified bucket e.g. the following command displays the summary of the bucket, `abc123`:

```
aws s3 ls s3://abc123 --summarize --recursive
```

The corresponding Python code will be like

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name = "abc123"

    total_objects = 0
    total_size = 0

    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Recursive=True)

    for page in page_iterator:
        if 'Contents' in page:
            total_objects += len(page['Contents'])
            for obj in page['Contents']:
                total_size += obj['Size']

    summary = {
        "TotalObjects": total_objects,
        "TotalSize": total_size
    }

    return summary
```

Comment: must start learning python soon...thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon S3 Storage Lens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage_lens_basics_metrics_recommendations.html) *"provides a single view of object storage usage and activity across your entire Amazon S3 storage. It includes drilldown options to generate insights at the organization, account, Region, bucket, or even prefix level."* However, the ability to obtain metrics at a *Prefix* level requires Advanced metrics, which is priced at `$0.20 per million objects monitored per month`. There is a [boto3 library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3control.html#s3control) that gives access to Storage Lens, but that seems to be about configuration rather than retrieving the actual metrics. (I haven't used it, so I'm not sure what's involved.)

Alternatively, you could call [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) for the desired Prefix. However, it only **returns a maximum of 1000 objects**, so you would need to keep calling it while `NextContinuationToken` is not null. Each call returns a `KeyCount`, which is the number of keys returned with the request.

Alternatively, if you use the resource-based call of `bucket.objects.all()`, then boto3 will perform the loop for you and will present back a *list* of `s3.ObjectSummary` objects. You can simply use `len()` on the list to obtain the count.

Both methods will be quite slow for buckets/folders with a large number of objects. Therefore, another option is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. It might not be 'current', but it is a very easy way to count the objects without having to loop through calls.